# How do I store the result of a query into a variable in HiveQL and then use it in another select statement?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

How do I store the result of a query into a variable in HiveQL and then use it in another select statement?

For example, whenever I store a normal variable and use it in a select statement it works just fine. 
   `SET a=1; SELECT CASE WHEN b > ${hiveconf:a} THEN NULL ELSE 1 from my_table`

But when I try and put a query into the variable, its seems to store the query instead of running it and storing the result. This then results in an error. 
   `SET a=SELECT MAX(num) FROM my_other_table; SELECT CASE WHEN b > ${hiveconf:a} THEN NULL ELSE 1 from my_table`

The error being: `cannot recognize input near 'select' 'max' '(' in select clause`

Does anyone know a work around to this? I am using Hive 0.13

Answer (score 2):

You cant do that only by hive.

If your hive query is controlled by outer script like `shell` or `python`.You can perform the first query, get the output and then put it in the next sql.

Or you can change your sql to use `join`.Your example code can be changed to

```
select case when b > t.a then NULL else 1 from my_table 
join (select max(num) a from my_other_table) t
```